# Проблема с удалением строки в php

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, если ввожу только первую часть кода

```
array_splice($f_arr1, $id, 1);
$f1 = fopen("file1.dat", "w");
for($i = 0; $i < count($f_arr1); $i++){
fwrite($f1, $f_arr1[$i]);
}
close($f1);
```

То тогда код работает, т.е. строка в файле удаляется, но если добавить ниже этот код, то вторая часть не работает.

```
array_splice($f_arr2, $id, 1);
$f2= fopen("../../file2", "w");
for($j = 0; $j < count($f_arr2); $j++){
fwrite($f2, $f_arr2[$j]);
}
close($f2);
```

Объяснит, пожалуйста, ошибки.

Comment: а ошибки выводятся какие-нибудь? Или может в логах есть что-нибудь?

Comment: Нет, не выводится

Answer (score 1):

Может быть он $id переопределяет?

Comment: нет, там $id одинаковый

Comment: тогда не верно указал путь к файлу или не указал расширение файла

Comment: Нет, все правильно, если удаляю первую часть, работает вторая, а если не удаляю ничего, то работает только первая.

Comment: нет функции close()...есть fclose();

Comment: получилось, спасибо